# How to make the android notification picture larger instead of a small badge like Youtube App?

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications, android-push-notification

I'm trying to implement the android notification picture like the youtube app, where the shrink big picture is larger than a normal icon, but still able to expand to a big picture style with a swipe. I'm assuming this is a android built in feature(if launcher supports) since youtube and some other apps are using it. But how to implement this style in code?

[image: youtube notification]

Comment: make your own custom notification layout